# How to make this particular rendered content in HTML as downloadable text file in Django?

Tags: html, django, function

```
<div class="container" >
          {% if sr %}
          {% for k in sr %}
          <p>Name: {{k.name}}</p>
          <p>Email: {{k.email}}</p>
          <p>Contact Number: {{k.contact_number}}</p>
          {% endfor %}
          {% endif %}
          </div>
```

THis is my html code and it is rendering perfectly when executed but i tried writing a function to download the rendered content as text file. And it is downloading the html code as text file not the actual rendered content. Please help me fix this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: post your "function".

Answer (score 0):

You can begin by declaring the following Javascript function:

```
function download(filename, text) {
    var element = document.createElement('a');
    element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text));
    element.setAttribute('download', filename);

    element.style.display = 'none';
    document.body.appendChild(element);

    element.click();

    document.body.removeChild(element);
}
```

Then you will need a function to call your download function. This function should have your text and filename:

```
function beginDownload(){

    // Generate download of the text file with some content
    var text = document.getElementById('text-content').innerHTML;
    var filename = "text.txt";
    download(filename, text);
}
```

Add the following id to your div:

```
<div class="container" id='text-content'>
    . . . 
</div>
```

Next add a button that will initiate the download:

```
<button type="button" onclick="beginDownload()">Download</button>
```

**Edit:**
Replace the following:

```
var text = document.getElementById('text-content').innerHTML;
```

with:

```
var text = document.getElementById('text-content').innerText;
```

to get the text only

Comment: `code` <p>Name: xyz</p>
          <p>Email: sdjf@sdjfb.com</p>
          <p>Contact Number: 3584368436</p>`code`




it is getting downloaded like this....in the same line. @Brandon Chetty I need it in list format.

Comment: See edit. You just need to change innerHTML to innerText in the beginDownload( ) function

Comment: i know JS in html is a bad idea.....any other solutions using python in views.py file?